# DBMS_SQL.BIND_VAR to a function (e.g. sysdate)

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, dynamic-sql

I think my problem is best described by an example:

```
Declare
  example1 varchar2(300) := 'sysdate';
  example2  varchar2(300) := 'null';
  example3  varchar2(300) := 'user';
  example4  varchar2(300) := '''Just some Text''';

  cursor_name INTEGER;
  rows_processed INTEGER;
BEGIN

    cursor_name := dbms_sql.open_cursor;

    DBMS_SQL.PARSE(cursor_name, 'UPDATE table_name SET column = :x', DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);
    DBMS_SQL.BIND_VARIABLE(cursor_name, ':x', example1);

    rows_processed := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(cursor_name);
    DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(cursor_name);
end;
/
```

All the "exampleX" variables will be bound as a varchar2 and not be "translated".

I previously used Execute Immediate but had to switch to DBMS_SQL because of performance optimizations. With Execute Immediate there are of course no problems if you use this approach:

```
Execute Immediate 'UPDATE table_name SET column = ' || example1;
```

But I can't think of a way to archieve this with BIND_VARIABLE.

(Of course I could concat the variables at the PARSE statement like with Execute Immediate but I think I will loose performance this way. Performance is highly important in this case)

---

Edit:

An example, closer to reality would be:

Copying data from one DB(SRC) to another DB(DEST), where I have this helper table:

```
CREATE TABLE "DEST_TAB_COLUMNS" 
   (    "OWNER" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
    "TABLE_NAME" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
    "COLUMN_NAME" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
    "DATA_TYPE" VARCHAR2(106 BYTE), 
    "OPERATION_TYPE" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
    "OPERATION_FUNCTION" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE)
   ) ;
```

In this Table I define which columns I am interested in on the DEST side.
And I have the option to define a "OPERATION_FUNCTION" to replace a certain column value.

So an entry would look like:

SRC_OWNER_NAME | SAMPLE_TABLE | SAMPLE_COL | VARCHAR2 | REPLACE | 'null'

SRC_OWNER_NAME | SAMPLE_TABLE | SAMPLE_COL2 | DATE | REPLACE | sysdate

On the SRC side I define which data I want to have transvered. This is a simple table which looks basically like:

```
CREATE TABLE "SRC_TRANSFER_DATA" 
   (    "OWNER" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
    "TABLE_NAME" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
    "WHERE_CLAUSE" VARCHAR2(300 BYTE), 
   ) ;
```

Example:
TESTOWNER | SAMPLE_TABLE | SPECIAL_COLUMN = 123

Now the program loops (on DEST) over the SRC_TRANSFER_DATA and constructs a MERGE statement. In order to do this it also looks in the DEST_TAB_COLUMNS table if there is a Rule for this table&column.
If there is a rule I add the bindvariable to my collection :

```
l_hostvariable_map(':p'||l_hostvar_cnt) := r_col.operation_function;
```

At the end I will look over this collection to make the binds.
The final Merge (in short) could look like this:

```
MERGE INTO dest_table dest 
USING 
(SELECT table_column FROM src_table WHERE special_column= :p1) 
src ON 
(dest.special_column= :p2) 
WHEN matched 
THEN UPDATE SET 
dest.column1=src.column1,dest.column2= :p3,dest.column3= :p4
WHEN NOT matched 
THEN INSERT 
(dest.column1,dest.column2,dest.column3) 
VALUES 
(src.column1,:p5,:p6)
```

Some of the :pX are a "function". Like in the example before the edit.

I hope this makes it clearer and not more complicated ;)

Comment: For clarification: The example variables here are actually fields in a table. Thats why its "sysdate" as a string and not var := sysdate; Because the table has the information what "function" should be called for a variable. And I have to use DBMS_SQL because we have a dynamic number of bind variables

Comment: I don't understand, can you please provide less "fiction" example which is closer to your **real** code. `SYSDATE`, `USER` or `NULL` are for sure not column names of any tables.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Done. I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Check [BIND_VARIABLE documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sql.htm#ARPLS68242):

> Notice that BIND_VARIABLE is overloaded to accept different Datatype.

So, your code should look like this:

```
example1 DATE := SYSDATE;
example2  varchar2(300) := NULL;
example3  varchar2(30) := USER;
example4  varchar2(300) := 'Just some Text';
```

In case you use `Execute Immediate`, better use

```
Execute Immediate 'UPDATE table_name SET column = :a' USING example1;
```

btw, in earlier Oracle releases (i.e. Oracle 10) there was indeed a performance difference in using `Execute Immediate` or the `DBMS_SQL` package. Usually `DBMS_SQL` was faster. However, in current releases I don't get any performance difference anymore when I compare them. Of course you will get similar performance only if you use bind-variables in any case.

Also note, using bind-variables are in 99.9% faster that static code - use them whenever possible. It is also beneficial in terms of SQL-Injection and quoting issues.

**Update:**

Based on your input your procedure may look like this one:

```
Declare
  val_date date;
  var_varchar varchar2(3000);
  var_number number;

  cursor_name INTEGER;
  rows_processed INTEGER;
BEGIN

   for aCol in (select * from DEST_TAB_COLUMNS) loop   
      cursor_name := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
      DBMS_SQL.PARSE(cursor_name, 'UPDATE '||aCol.table_name||' SET '||aCol.COLUMN_NAME||' = :val', DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);

      if aCol.DATA_TYPE = 'DATE' then
          execute immediate 'begin :res := '||aCol.OPERATION_FUNCTION||'; end;' using out val_date;
          DBMS_SQL.BIND_VARIABLE(cursor_name, ':x', val_date);
      elsif aCol.DATA_TYPE = 'VARCHAR2' then
          execute immediate 'begin :res := '||aCol.OPERATION_FUNCTION||'; end;' using out val_varchar;
          DBMS_SQL.BIND_VARIABLE(cursor_name, ':x', val_varchar);
      elsif aCol.DATA_TYPE = 'NUMBER' then
          execute immediate 'begin :res := '||aCol.OPERATION_FUNCTION||'; end;' using out val_number;
          DBMS_SQL.BIND_VARIABLE(cursor_name, ':x', val_number);
      end if;
      rows_processed := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(cursor_name);
      DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(cursor_name);
   end loop;
end;
/
```

Of course, the procedure as above would be terribly slow because you process column-by-column and row-by-row. Anyway, I assume you get an idea how your code can look like. You function may also return not only a single value but several values in a PL/SQL table.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please read my comment I added to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Where your example goes wrong is it tries to pass the text string 'sysdate' instead of a date value. Bind variables are for passing values, not constructing query text.

```
declare
    example1        date := sysdate;  -- an actual date value, not the word 'sysdate'!
    cursor_id       integer;
    rows_processed  integer;
begin
    cursor_id := dbms_sql.open_cursor;

    dbms_sql.parse(cursor_id, 'update demo set dt = :x', dbms_sql.native);
    dbms_sql.bind_variable(cursor_id, 'x', example1);
    rows_processed := dbms_sql.execute(cursor_id);

    dbms_sql.close_cursor(cursor_id);
end;
```

(The second argument to `dbms_sql.bind_variable` is `name`, so I pass `'x'` not `':x'`, although it appears to accept either.)

As Wernfried has already pointed out, you don't need all of the complexity of DBMS_SQL for this, as you could just use `execute immediate`:

```
declare
    example1 date := sysdate;
begin
    execute immediate 'update demo set dt = :x' using example1;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks to you as well. But please read my comment I added to the question. It seems my example was too simple :D

Answer (score 0):

As I undestand you want to replace some **"binds"** with function. And it functions should be executed in run time for example:

```
 execute immediate 'UPDATE TEST_TABLE 
    SET a = :bind_function'
  using 'substr(a,1,10)';
```

should be executed as :

```
 UPDATE TEST_TABLE 
    SET a = substr(a,1,10);
```

Oracle bind vriables are not allow to do it; 
But you may write your function to replace placeholders

```
  declare 
    l_sql varchar2(4000); 
    l_placeholder1 varchar2(4000) := '(\w+)\s+/\*placeholder_1\*/';
    l_function1    varchar2(4000) := 'substr(\1,1,10)';
    l_placeholder2 varchar2(4000) := '(\w+)\s+/\*placeholder_2\*/';
    l_function2    varchar2(4000) := 'nvl(\1,1000)';
  begin
    l_sql :=  'UPDATE TEST_TABLE 
    SET column_a = column_a /*placeholder_1*/
      , column_b = column_b /*placeholder_2*/
      , column_c = column_e /*placeholder_1*/
    where column_d /*placeholder_2*/ = 10';
    l_sql := REGEXP_REPLACE(l_sql,l_placeholder1,l_function1); 
    l_sql := REGEXP_REPLACE(l_sql,l_placeholder2,l_function2); 
    dbms_output.put_line(l_sql);  
    execute immediate l_sql;
  end;
```